# How to develop sharepoint application on a client machine

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint

I have a centralized Microsoft Sharepoint Server and SQL Server on Windows Server 2008 intalled. I am new to sharepoint. In my local machine i have installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Trial version. When i goto create new share point project in the visual studio, I am getting an error message saying,

"A sharepoint server is not installed on this computer. A sharepoint server must be installed to work with sharepoint projects"

Is it possible to develop the sharepoint application like this? if yes. can you please let me know what i can do?

--
Regards

Comment: You really need to accept some answers

Answer (score 2):

You should install SharePoint 2010 on that machine. Either install it on Windows 7-8 or Windows Server 2008-R2

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check this [Installing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 on Windows 7 x64](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/2011/03/installing-microsoft-sharepoint-server.html) along this follow [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx).

> you should have 64-bit version of Windows 7. then follow the step
>   mentioned in the above link.  Install the additional prerequisites carefully else the installation will cause some error.

Comment: Cant I use a centrally installed SharePoint Server on a local machine for the development?

Comment: yes.. you can .. check [this](http://www.techerator.com/2011/02/how-to-perform-sharepoint-development-on-a-client-workstation/) and [this](http://lemonharpy.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/remote-debugging-sharepoint-2010-solutions/)